# simple stack-based machine in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, hash, stack

I have to create a simple stack-based machine.  The instruction set consists of 5 instructions; push, pop, add, mult, end.  I accept a source code file that has an instruction section (.text) and a data section (.data) and then i must store these in memory by simulating a memory system that uses 32-bit addresses.

An example source code file that I have to store in memory might be

```
    .text
main:
    push X
    push Y
    add   //remove top two words in stack and add them then put result on top of stack
    pop (some memory address)  // stores result in the address
    end

    .data
X:  3    // allocate memory store the number 3
Y:  5
```

Any suggestion on how to do the memory system?  I should probably store data in one section (maybe an array?) and then instructions in another but i can't just use array indexes since I need to use 32-bit addresses in my code.

Edit:  Also is there a way to replace the X and Y with the actual address once I've assigned the number 3 and 5 to a space in memory (in my data array)? . . . kind of like a two pass assembler might do it.

Comment: if you follow my advice, return the 'address' (i.e. s->top) from  `push` function: i.e. declare it like `word push(stackp s, word w);`

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with arrays? If you know the size you need, they should work.
An address in your machine code would actually be an index in the array.

Using a 32-bit index with an array isn't a problem. Of course, not all indexes would be valid - only those from 0 to the size of the array. But do you need to simulate 4GB of memory, or can you set a limit on the memory size?

Comment: i can have a limit. . . hmm, ok I'm going to try and work this out somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the ugoren' answer (and a bit OT), I think a relatively interesting approach could be to extend your specification space with a `.stack` section, to be initialized by default to empty (like in your example).

That can be used to describe the expected intermediate stages of the computation (save/restore the actual state at some point).

To implement, I would use very simple code, like

file stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK
#define STACK

#include <stdio.h>

/* here should be implemented the constraint about 32 bits words... */
typedef int word;

typedef struct { int top; word* mem; int allocated; } stack;
typedef stack* stackp;

stackp new_stack();
void free_stack(stackp);

void push(stackp s, word w);
word pop(stackp p);

/* extension */
stackp read(FILE*);
void write(stackp, FILE*);

#endif
```

file stack.c:

```
/* example implementation, use - arbitrary - chunks of 2^N */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

/* blocks are 256 words */
#define N (1 << 8)

stackp new_stack() {
  stackp s = calloc(1, sizeof(stack));
  s->mem = malloc((s->allocated = N) * sizeof(word));
  return s;
}
void free_stack(stackp s) {
  free(s->mem);
  free(s);
}

void push(stackp s, int w) {
  if (s->top == s->allocated) {
     s->allocated += N;
     s->mem = realloc(s->mem, s->allocated * sizeof(word));
  }
  s->mem[s->top++] = w;
}
word pop(stackp s) {
  if (s->top == 0) { /* exception */ }
  return s->mem[--(s->top)];
}
```

file main.c:

```
#include "stack.h"
int main() {

  stackp s = new_stack();
  word X = 3;
  word Y = 5;

  push(s, X);
  push(s, Y);
  word Z = pop(s) + pop(s);

  printf("Z=%d\n", Z);

  free_stack(s);
}
```

file makefile:

```
main: main.c stack.c
```

to build:

```
make
```

to test:

```
./main
Z=8
```

It's worth noting some difference WRT ugoren' answer: I stress on *data hiding*, a valuable part of implementation, keeping details about actual functions in a separate file. There we can add many details, for instance about a maximum stack size (actually not enforced there), error handling, etc...

*edit*: to get the 'address' of a pushed word

```
word push(stackp s, int w) {
  if (s->top == s->allocated) {
     s->allocated += N;
     s->mem = realloc(s->mem, s->allocated * sizeof(word));
  }
  s->mem[s->top] = w;
  return s->top++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Key to the memory system is to limit the range of the memory. In OS you can access only several sections of the memory.

So in you particular program you can say, that valid programs can contain addressees starting at 0x00004000 and the memory available to your machine is for example 4 MB.

Then in your program you create virtual memory space, of size 4MB and store it's beginning.

Below is an example; bear in mind it's an example, you have to adjust the parameters accordingly.

```
virtual memory start - 0x00006000 (get from malloc, or static initialization. or whatever)
stack machine memory start - 0x00004000
offset - 0x2000 (to align addresses in you OS and in your stack machine, you have to add 0x2000 to the stack machine address to get pointer to your array (in reality the offset can be negative).
```

If you actually need an index to array, just subtract beginning of your virtual memory from the pointer.